# Replacing a range based on criteria using a macro vba

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance. I am pretty new to VBA I am trying to have a single column of cells copied from one column and pasted into a number based on a single criteria, which can change. I have a list in column E and a list in Column F. I want to be able to pull data from only certain cells in column E based on the adjacent cell in column F. Basically, whatever name I type into "L7", the macro will pull any data from column E that corresponds to that name. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Value = "" then Exit Sub
    Dim rn
    rn = 15
    If Target.row = 7 And Target.Column = 12 Then
      For Each cel in Range("E:E")
        If cel.Offset(0,1).value = cel.Value Then
          Range("L" & rn).Value = cel.Value
          rn = rn+1
        End If
      Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, this does what I want it to do. I even works if I change the name in cell "L7". The problem is that it does not replace all the data from the previous time the macro ran. If I have a list of 20 names and 10 names and run the macro to pull the list of 20 names first, it won't clear out the extra names from that list when I pull the second.

I attempted several different things on this. I tried:

```
Sub Clear_cells()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L15:L100").ClearContents
End Sub
```

That didn't return any error messages but nothing happened.

I then tried:

```
If Range("L15:100").Value <> "" Then
    Range("L15:100").ClearContents
End If
```

That line of code gave me a type 13 mismatch error.

Simply put, I need the entire range of cells where the data is being pasted to change and there be no leftover data from the previous time the macro ran.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by your example - I thought you were trying to compare column F to cell L7, but this line compares column E to column F for each row: `If cel.Offset(0,1).value = cel.Value Then`

Comment: Clear_Cells works for me (ie it clears all cells from L15:L100 on Sheet1). Are you actually running Clear_Cells as a separate macro and it's doing nothing?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Sorry for the confusion. What I have is a two lists of names. One is of employees and the other is a list of managers. The employee list is in column E and the manager list is in column F. The manager name directly adjacent to the employee name is that employee's manager. I want to type the manager's name into L7 and have the macro pull all employee names associated with that manager.

Comment: @Jane When I tried Clear_Cells, it would only work if I ran a separate macro. It was written in a module and would have to be activated. I would like for it to clear L15:L100 whenever L7 is modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the other macro from within your code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Value = "" then Exit Sub
  Call Clear_Cells()
    Dim rn
    rn = 15
    If Target.row = 7 And Target.Column = 12 Then
      For Each cel in Range("E:E")
        If cel.Offset(0,1).value = cel.Value Then
          Range("L" & rn).Value = cel.Value
          rn = rn+1
        End If
      Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this can also be done using array formulas, which I feel is a better option as code will not be run every time a cell changes on the worksheet.

Comment: There we go! Thank you :)